Bound states between neutrinos using Schrödinger's equation?
I would like to see if it's possible that neutrinos (with sufficiently slow velocities) could form bound states in a universe with matter (such as ours)
There is a cosmic neutrino background in the universe which is probably the coldest neutrinos we could find (meaning slowest speeds). Slower neutrinos would heat up by thermalizing to the background.
I have been told that their wave function is around 1cm in length at those temperatures. I would think there is simply too much other matter around for the neutrino to form some sort of bound gravitational state but I'm not sure.
However I've read that I could plug this into Schrödinger’s equation and replace the potential term with the gravitational potential and see what the bound states energy are (I'd have to guess at the mass of the neutrinos, but I could use some upper limit for your guess)
However, I'm studying physics by my own (as I come from another scientific field that is not very related with it) and I have a bit of trouble understanding Schrödinger's equation
I don't think this would be difficult, but could someone help me how to figure this out? How can I solve the equation for this? Which steps should I take?

If you use the Newtonian potential, then I think this is the same solution as for the Hydrogen-like atoms. The possible difference lies in the interpretations of the counterpart of the Bohr radius. However, note that neutrinos have 1/2 spin, so the Dirac equation is better suited for such a calculation.

Linked.

A quick back-of-the envelope estimate, in the style of Fermi:
For a neutrino mass of m ~ 1 eV, and a Planck mass M ~ $10^{27}$ eV, and supplanting the newtonian potential $(m/M)^2/r$ for the Coulomb potential $e^2/r$, yields a Bohr radius for such neutrinuum atoms of
$$
r \sim M^2/m^3 \sim 10^{54}/\hbox{eV} \sim 10^{47} ~~\hbox{m}.
$$
Compare this to the present diameter, $10^{27}$ m, of the entire universe...

So we have to just wait long enough ...

@CosmasZachos in the question that you linked (https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27498/quantum-mechanical-gravitational-bound-states) the OP asks after getting the answers: "I guess no place is sufficiently empty at least because background radiation is everywhere. Maybe these creatures will become relevant in a very distant future when the background radiation cools off considerably?". I have basically the same question now, if not now, would neutrinos be able to form bound states once everything in the universe has cooled down?

My point above is that such bound states don’t fit in the universe now or in the conceivable universe in future, so the are irrelevant; not that they are so weakly bound so as to be unstable…

@CosmasZachos two questions: 1# when you say "in the conceivable universe in future" what scale of years are you referring to? 2# then the conclusion is that these bound states are impossible no matter how far we go into the future of the universe?


Indeed, because, 1. Compare todays size with its expansion rate…


@CosmasZachos however, in this question (https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/57778/references-about-neutrinos-getting-clumped-in-structures-in-the-future) that I made about whether there could be structures made from neutrinos, the answer linked a paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0408241) in which the authors studied that neutrinos could form "halos" around sufficiently large dark matter (and baryonic matter) potentials. Compact objects like neutrino stars have also been proposed.

@CosmasZachos If it is so obvious by looking at the Schrödinger equation that neutrinos cannot form bound states, why do these physicists say that is possible?

Ach, no! You are misreading their language. They say they do not consider classical galaxy-neutrino “bound states”, like the sun-earth one, not quantum onia.

@CosmasZachos thank you for the clarification, however I assume you meant "They say they do consider classical galaxy-neutrino “bound states”" right?

They say they do not, but that’s what they are excluding. They never even dreamt of quantum onia.

@CosmasZachos perhaps I'm mistenterpreting this again but if they do not consider classical galaxy-neutrino gravitational "bound states" (as you said like the Earth-Sun system) how can they are studying gravitational clustering of neutrinos around cold dark matter and baryonic matter structures? I mean, gravitational clustering means that the neutrinos are being attracted by gravity thus forming a (gravitational) bound state with those structures, right?

This falls solidly in their classical halo calculations, and I cannot read their paper for you. Perhaps their fields' conventions do not call halos "gravitational bound states". But completely off subject for quantum bound states.
